# How to use couchbase with an existing PHP+Postgres server application

Tags: php, postgresql, couchbase, offlineapps, couchbase-sync-gateway

I want to use Couchbase for my Sync Only needs with my existing PHP-Postgres Application.

So this is how i plan to use it.

1. changes in server are pushed to couchbase sync gateway ( to update couchbase server db )
2. Hence couchbase should automatically update the mobiles according to channels.
3. Changes from mobiles can be pushed to My postgres server using Couchbase web hooks.
4. Thus ( theoretically ) all syncing should happen smoothly.

However before implementing this architecture i have come across a few questions while researching which I’m not able to find suitable answers to.

Please help . .

**Questions**

1. What would be the best technique too handle file sync ? ( should i simply convert the files to base64 strings and treat them like regular json data in couchbase ?)
2. If i update the couchbase server from my server. Wouldn’t that also trigger the web hook ? How do i suppress/ignore the web hook in case of changes from my server ?
3. Also Couchbase sync gateway mentions that for Authentication i need to have the server setup on the same domain name as the main server ( refer : [Couchbases Custom (indirect) Authentication](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/administering-sync-gateway/authenticating-users/index.html) ). I want to keep couchbase on a different server for simplicity and load. How can i have them on different servers and still not run into the above session cookie limitation ?

Comment: no solution to this yet ? @Couchbase guys. Please help.